# Is the 2011 Macbook Pro body equivalent to the 2012 model?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair, unibody

My mid-2012 Macbook Pro's body is damaged beyond repair but the internal parts are still functional. Is it possible that I could assemble the parts into a 2011 body of the same size and have a functional laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. You could attempt it, since they're both about the same size, but I don't think that it would work due to the small differences that will likely exist between the two models. I'd just buy a 2012 body off of eBay.